# iPhone 5s, send "volume up" signal

Tags: iphone, ear-phones

As many are aware, one can snap a photo using the "volume up" button and even the same button on the earbud volume controls.  I am trying to control the camera remotely and need more distance than the earbuds provide.  How can I generate the signal?  Are the specs available?  Is it a proprietary control or a simple on/off pulse on one of the three conductors through the stereo jack?  I tried a simple 1/8" stereo cable extension, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you considered Bluetooth options? I have heard that sometimes, even a normal Bluetooth earbud will trigger that function - but I haven't tested that.

Comment: That's a good idea.. I will try and report back.

Answer (score 1):

There is a proprietary micro-controller in the Applebuds, so you won't be able to simulate it.

Maybe you could try a jack extension cord. (beware, you'll need a jack with 4 connectors).

Comment: I was afraid it was proprietary.  I did try a jack extension, but it was 3-wire, I believe... that was likely my issue.  I will try this as well and report back.